# extract iPhone Data

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I'm trying to extract about 72000 SInt32s from the iPhone, but not sure what the best approach is.  Using printf or NSLog to the console basically crashes my program and my computer.  I tried redirecting stderr to a file, but I run into the same problem.  Was wondering what the best way is to extract this data so I can later use it on my desktop for plotting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on a lot of things. For example, what format are those numbers in? You could do a HTTP POST to a netcat sitting on the desktop machine:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://desktop:3000/"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:…];
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]
    initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
NSAssert(connection, @"Failed to create connection.");
```

And on the desktop:

```
$ nc -l 3000
```

You’ll get something like this:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: YourApp1.0 CFNetwork/422.15.2 Darwin/9.6.0 (i386) (MacBook4%2C1)
Accept-Language: en-us
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: xxx
Connection: keep-alive
Host: 127.0.0.1:3000

//data
```

Comment: What exactly do You need help with? The “server” part (the code on the desktop), or the “client” part, the code on the device?